# SQL query to display a particular content type?

Tags: 6, database

I want to create a view which displays a list of a particular content type. I only have access to the database and I need to figure out the list of content type through view; therefore, I am thinking to write SQL for it. Is it possible to do?

I am using Drupal 6.

Comment: are looking for sql query or views module to display content?

Comment: no i want to create a view using SQL query

Comment: @RajenderRajan Merci for the accept! Better late then never, right?

Comment: Yeah !! Thanx again !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## List all content types

To build a list of all your content types in a Drupal 6 site, use an SQL query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `node_type`
```

The values in the `type` column in the results you get, corresponds to the machine name for each of the content types you have in your site.

## List all nodes of a particular content type

Here is an SQL query to display a list of nodes of content type `story` in a Drupal 6 site:

```
SELECT *  FROM `node` WHERE `type` = 'story'
```

Change `story` to the machine name of your particular content type (= any of the values in the `type` column from the first SQL above).

Comment: Moreover, what would be the SQL query for Content ,Content Type and its Taxonomy ?